# Go scope and lifetime of shadowed variables inside for loop?

Tags: go

I am playing with Golang and wrote my very little HTTP client. I repeatedly check the response in case it is unqualified, in which case I shall ask for a new request:

```
url := getUrl(baseUrl, options ...)
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
checkErr(err)

for retry > 0 {
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    checkErr(err)
    if badRet := resp.Header.Get("SOMETHING-HERE"); badRet {
        req, err = http.NewRequest("GET", getUrl(baseUrl, newOptions ...))
        checkErr(err)
        continue
    }
}
...
```

But it seems Golang does not assign the new request to the declared `req`. However:

```
...
for retry > 0 {
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    checkErr(err)
    if badRet := resp.Header.Get("SOMETHING-HERE"); badRet {
        req, err = http.NewRequest("GET", getUrl(baseUrl, newOptions ...))
        checkErr(err)
        fmt.Printf("new req: %v", req)
        continue
    }
}
...
```

seems to do the trick. My only question is why?

I am not a manual reader but I would love to have some. Or blogs. I believe the behaviours should relate to scope and lifetime of shadowed variables?

-------------- edit --------------

What I was saying was by adding a line of

```
fmt.Printf("new req: %v", req)
```

the allocated new request was assigned. Otherwise, the assignment would be discarded.

I tried to make a reproducible example, but shamefully failed. I cannot directly post all my codes, they contain my personal data. I will list some new reproductive examples once I finished them.

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense: Construction a new request without executing (Do-ing) it looks strange. Please come up with a selfcontained, runnable example that demonstrates the problem. And the name of the language is Go.

Comment: @Volker My bad. I made a mistake when copying and pasting my codes. Have been updated. Looks like Go is the preferred name other than Golang

Comment: Your code still makes no sense as both samples are the same.

Comment: @Chien the way you are re-assigning the `req` variable (using `=`) from within the `if` statement is fine (in both examples), after the `continue` statement the `client.Do` call at the top of the loop's body will execute the new request. If that doesn't do what you expect it to do then either the examples are not representative of the real code (in which case you should provide a [mcve]) or your expectations are unjustified (in which case you should __precisely__ and __in detail__ describe the expected behaviour and the actual behaviour).